# rails_admin gives me this error translation missing: en.admin.help.post.admin_id in the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I have an admin that can create posts in rails_admin

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, inverse_of: :admin
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :admin, inverse_of: :posts
```

With this code when I create a new post I have the option to select which admin I want to assign it to but I don't want that. The field should be hidden and the current_admin should be the one associated with the post.

so I added this to my rails_admin initializer:

```
    config.model Post do
     edit do
       configure :admin do
         visible false
       end

       field :admin_id, :hidden do
         visible true
         default_value do
           bindings[:view]._current_user
         end
       end
     end
   end
 end
```

and this:

```
  config.authenticate_with do
     warden.authenticate! scope: :admin
  end
  config.current_user_method(&:current_admin)
```

when I restart the server and go to New Post all I get is this

```
 translation missing: en.admin.help.post.admin_id
```

it does not render the form but has the save buttons.

I tried everything and can't figure it out. I never loaded any Il8n either. any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a bug fix that wasn't a part of the newest gem release. to fix it you have grab the latest version from the master branch by adding this to your gem file.

```
gem 'rails_admin', github: 'sfreik/rails_admin'
```

and do a:

```
bundle update rails_admin
```